# Create master-detail page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to create a master/detail page in my wordpress site. In other words, when someone clicks a username from a list of names,that link will take them to a page with the user's complete details, how do I create a link for each user displayed that will open a details page about JUST that user? I dont want any code or anything like that, just a pointer as to which wordpress functions i should be looking into. i would really love to do this without a plugin, but if theres no other way then im willing to go that route. ive searched on google but found nothing relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should get all users using [get_users](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users).

Then you need to cycle trought this users using `foreach` or `while` ( it doent's matter which one you will choose )

In your cicle you should get create a link tag and add the author link using [the_author_meta( $field, $userID );](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/the_author_meta) where the `$field` will be replaced by `user_url`.

Comment: the users are inserted into a custom table, not a regular wordpress table so using the_author_meta doesnt work.

Comment: Then you will need to create a custom SQL query. Can you please provide the structure of your custom table?

Comment: these are all my columns:
`bride_id`, `bride_name`, `bride_parents`, `groom_name`, `groom_parents`, `venue`, `the_date`, `phone`, `address`, `photographer`, `photographer_ad`, `photographer_tel`, `baker`, `baker_ad`, `baker_tel`, `bride_image`, `cake_image`, `status`

Comment: Well I am not sure that I can provide a solution here, because it will require a lot of custom coding. First you need to create a template where you can show their information. Then you will need to create a link to that template and pass the user id as `$_GET` parameter. For example `http://example.com/link-to-custom-tempate?user_id=15`
where user_id will be `bride_id`

In created template you will need to get that param and retrieve the user information.

Comment: that sounds like a great solution. how do i open this page template from a link in the master page though? i tried:

<a href="http://localhost/folder_name/wordpress/wp-content/themes/theme_name/user_profile.php">

but this is just not working. Any ideas.

Comment: You need to assign a page to that template first. You can read more about here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use

Then you should use that page link to add the $_GET parameter.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your help Stan! great stuff :)

Comment: Great, if this answer helped you, you should consider accepting it, so it will help other people facing the same or similar problem.